# issue to connect jupyter sparkmagic kernel to kerberized livy server

Tags: pyspark, jupyter, kerberos, livy

please help if you have any idea:
I am trying to connect kerberized Hortonworks hadoop clusters livy server with jupyter, I have 401 error when connecting

Is it possible to connect sparkmagic to kerberized spark livy server? if it is then I think I have some misconfiguration in the sparkmagic config json.
username and password is the technical user which runs server and have right of impersonation in the hadoop cluster(proxy user) not actual username when I login in the jupyterhub

its part of my config.json:

```
  "kernel_python_credentials" : {
    "username": "username",
    "password": "password",
    "url": "http://mylivy.server:8999",
    "auth": "Kerberos"
  }
  "logging_config": {
    "version": 1,
    "formatters": {
      "magicsFormatter": { 
        "format": "%(asctime)s\t%(levelname)s\t%(message)s",
        "datefmt": ""
      }
    },
    "handlers": {
      "magicsHandler": { 
        "class": "hdijupyterutils.filehandler.MagicsFileHandler",
        "formatter": "magicsFormatter",
        "home_path": "~/.sparkmagic"                                                                                                                                                   
      }                                                                                                                                                                                
    },                                                                                                                                                                                 
    "loggers": {                                                                                                                                                                       
      "magicsLogger": {                                                                                                                                                                
        "handlers": ["magicsHandler"],                                                                                                                                                 
        "level": "DEBUG",                                                                                                                                                              
        "propagate": 0                                                                                                                                                                 
      }                                                                                                                                                                                
    }                                                                                                                                                                                  
  },                                                                                                                                                                                   

  "wait_for_idle_timeout_seconds": 15,
  "livy_session_startup_timeout_seconds": 600,
```

.................................................etc............................

this is error message when I try some "hello world" in the spark or pyspark notebook or shell in the jupyter:

print("Hello World")

> The code failed because of a fatal error:     Invalid status code '401'
>   from http://mylivy.server:8999/sessions with error payload: 
>     Error 401
>
> ### HTTP ERROR: 401
>
> Problem accessing
>   /sessions. Reason:
>
> ```
>     Authentication required
> ```
>
> ---
>
> Powered by Jetty://
>   9.3.24.v20180605
>
> ---
>
> .
>
> Some things to try: a) Make sure Spark has enough available resources
>   for Jupyter to create a Spark context. b) Contact your Jupyter
>   administrator to make sure the Spark magics library is configured
>   correctly. c) Restart the kernel.

Answer (score 0):

(UPDATE)
I just have found the reason why the error occurred: problem was that there was not ticket on the system where the notebook app was launched, kinit command resolved the issue. P.S. also username and password was not needed when use kerberos in the config.json

Comment: it's not working, i kinited but still 401